# Filtering based on relationships properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following graph: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=qeuv73

I'd like to design a cypher query, which will return the following nodes for 'first user':

- node 7 ("dep 2")

The conditions, are such that, in order for a node to be returned, user has to have all of it's dependencies. A user owns a node, when there is a relationship of HAS between the user and the node.
That is simple enough. The following query should do the trick:

```
MATCH (a:Dep)-[:REQUIRES]->(req:Dep)
WITH collect(req) AS requirements, a

MATCH (ub:Dep)<-[:HAS]-(:User)
WITH collect(ub) AS userDeps, requirements, a

WHERE ALL (req IN requirements WHERE req IN userDeps)
RETURN a
```

The problem start, when I want to introduce another condition, which is the value of user's relationship of HAS (data property) has to be either equal or greater than a particular dependency's data.

To put that into the example: "dep 2" fulfills both of the conditions, whereas "dep 1" does not, bcause it has a REQUIRES relationship to "dep 4" with data = 6, and user's HAS relationship to that node is equal to 5. The other dependency for "dep 1" is however fulfilled (as the levels are euqal).

Could anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

In other words, I want to iterate though every node Dep, check all of the REQUIRES relationships for each and every one of them and then return all the nodes that have resolved all the requirements for a particular user. Resolved means that a user has a HAS relationship with every requirement and that HAS.data >= REQUIRES.data

Comment: Do the dependencies cascade to multiple levels?  Is there a `data` property on all relationships?  Does `HAS.data` have to `>=` a single `REQUIRES.data` or does it have to `>=` the sum of all related `REQUIRES.data`?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits no they don't cascade to multiple levels. 
There is a data proeprty on all of the relationships.
Neither. It has to >= to all the corresponding REQUIRES. As in:
dep 1-> requires (data: 5) dep2
dep 1 -> required (data: 6) dep3
then to match user has to have dep2 with data at least 5 AND dep3 with data at least 6

Comment: @FrobberOfBits actually yes, they can cascade to multiple levels. That shouldn't matter though in this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference.
If you have a task that seems to be too complex to handle by one (or indeed combined) cypher queries you can extend Neo4J functionality.

You can write your own module and deploy it with Neo4J. One of the ways to do it is to use GraphAware Runtime.
https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/runtime